# Can I install LXDE or an equivalent desktop on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, linux, desktop, lxde

Okay, so this is probably going to be a really stupid question but...

Is there any possible way to put on a Linux-based LXDE, XFCE or equivalent lightweight desktop for Windows 7? I'm looking to speed up my computer's overall performance, without changing too much physically (As its a laptop, I don't think I could anyhow).

Again, I think it is a really stupid question, seeing as Windows and Linux are two separate entities (and I know that), but I'm trying to open up as much resources as I'm able to.

Comment: If you're looking to improve performance, the answer is no. There are ways to get LXDE, XFCE or equivalent installed on Windows 7, but all methods will leave Windows still running in the background, leaving you with no performance gain. Would you be open to installing a lighweight Linux distro on your laptop?

Comment: Yeah, I thought that was about right. Windows is pretty closed-source, and very limited in expansion and customization. @fideli Yeah, I already have before, but switching between Linux and Windows is a bit of an interesting change; I use a lot of windows-native programs, unfortunately. :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can install a desktop manager like those you've mentioned onto Windows. However, it will not provide a performance gain. In all likelihood, it will be slower than the native Windows environment.

These desktop managers use a completely different stack for interfacing with your graphics hardware and the OS kernel: X. Windows uses its own system. Aside from the fact that Windows currently doesn't allow a (simple, at least) way to switch out its window manager for an alternate, any programs that you run have to be built and linked with your desktop manager's APIs for it to work with it.

LXDE, XFCE, and other Linux-based desktop and window managers all use X under the hood, so you can swap out one desktop for another and still use all your X programs. If you want to install these on Windows, you will have to install an X stack on top of Windows, which will often either interface with the Windows desktop manager, or operate on top of it, independently. Then you can use an X desktop/window manager. Any Windows native programs that you run, however, will not know of X and so will not use this desktop manager. You can install other X programs on Windows and run them within it, however, but they likely won't perform as well as if you just installed Linux on the machine directly.

There will be no performance gain, at best, because you are running additional things on top of what Windows already provides, not supplanting one system for a lighter-weight one.

At worst, and most likely, you will experience a performance loss. The X stack implementations that are out there (of which I primarily am familiar with Cygwin/X) do not have full access to your graphics hardware. As desktop and windows managers these days are compositing, they often offload a lot of operations to your GPU. OpenGL support in X on Windows is limited, so everything will probably be handled via the CPU, which is slower.

I've personal experience with this, having recently tried this out by installing Cygwin/X and building Fluxbox to run on a Windows 7 machine. I ran it with a compositor, but it was much slower than Windows' native desktop manager for precisely this reason.

Comment: Yeah, I figured about as much. I've been playing with some things here and there, but never the things you mentioned; I wasn't aware of them at the time. Thank you for the information! This helped save me some time!

Answer (score 2):

While you cannot install a lightweight GUI, you can improve performance of the *slightly* by right clicking `My Computer`, select `Properties`, then select `Advanced System Settings`, the `Advanced` tab, then select Performance `Settings`, and check `Adjust for best performance`.

Answer (score -1):

There is a way to get a more Linux shell on Windows, Black Box.
BB4Win will let you install the Black Box shell onto windows. It even has Themes that you can download and install.

Should be OK with Windows 7, you can try it without actually setting it as the default desktop and just re-run Explorer when you want Windows back.

I have used it with XP a long time ago because I hate looking at the same desktop for too long (in decades).

I don't know how it performs with Windows 8 or 10 now though.

This might be an old question but I thought I'd drop this in for referncing.